# Getting data from three tables codeigniter using Query builder

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have three tables in database.

1.george_holiday_users(id,package_id,name,email)

2.george_holiday_passengers(id,user_id,type,name,age,gender)

3.george_packages (id,package_name,description)

Now i want to select data from  three tables 
george_holiday_users,george_packages and george_holiday_passengers tables  where george_holiday_users.id=george_holiday_passengers.user_id and george_holiday_users.package_id=george_packages.id

```
    $this->db->select('*');
           $this->db->from('george_holiday_users');
           $this->db->join('george_holiday_passengers', 'george_holiday_users.id = george_holiday_passengers.user_id');
           $this->db->join('george_packages', 'george_packages.id = george_holiday_users.package_id');
           $query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```

But i will the data from only george_holiday_users table.

Comment: What results are you getting and are you sure you should be getting the result you seem to be expecting?  Are you calling `$query->result()` to get the result set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$query = $this->db->select("SELECT * 
                FROM george_holiday_users 
                INNER JOIN george_holiday_passenger ON george_holiday_users.id = george_holiday_passengers.user_id
                INNER JOIN george_packages ON george_holiday_users.package_id = george_packages.id");
$result = $query->result_array();
return $result;
```

Comment: Let me try your answer

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.`id = ghu`.`package_id`' at line 1

`SELECT `SELECT * FROM george_holiday_users AS ghu LEFT JOIN george_holiday_passengers AS ghp ON ghu`.`id = ghp`.`user_id LEFT JOIN george_packages` AS `gp ON gp`.`id = ghu`.`package_id``

Comment: check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.`id =` `george_holiday_users`.`package_id`' at line 1

SELECT `SELECT * FROM george_holiday_users LEFT JOIN george_holiday_passenger ON george_holiday_users`.`id = george_holiday_passengers`.`user_id LEFT JOIN george_packages ON george_packages`.`id =` `george_holiday_users`.`package_id`

Comment: is this fields are in table?? `user_id`, `package_id`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99663/discussion-between-blessan-kurien-and-abdulla).

Answer (score 1):

My opinion is that you can remove the `george_holiday_passengers` and add the `type,age,gender` columns to the `george_holiday_users` as looking to it; its only a extended data of the `holiday_users` table
and build query with your new database tables.

```
$query = $this->db->select('u.*, p.package_name, p.description')
       ->from('george_holiday_users u')
       ->join('george_packges p', 'u.package_id = p.id', 'left')
       ->get();

return $query->result();
```

anyway, you can achieved the result using this query.

```
$query = $this->db->select('u.*, hp.type, hp.name AS passengers_name, hp.age, hp.gender, p.package_name, p.description')
       ->from('george_holiday_users u')
       ->join('george_holiday_passengers hp', 'hp.user_id = u.id', 'left')
       ->join('george_packges p', 'u.package_id = p.id', 'left')
       ->get();

return $query->result();
```

you should be careful about the column names because on your database there are a lot of columns with the same names, It might affect your query when your using joins, etc.

Hope that helps.